# How to unmount an internal disk

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have two hard disks installed in my computer. I played with the "Mounting options" for my second hard disk from the "Disk" tool.

Since that I can't access my second hard disk and every time I reboot i get this message 
[image: Error message]

[image: Error message 2]
[image: When trying to open the secondary drive]

I tried to change the SATA port but this didn't change anything. I tried mounting and unmounting from "Disk" but it didn't fix it.

How can I Fix this. How can I unmounted this drive and mount it again in the right way.

*The disk contains NO important data.

[image: FSTAB and lsblk]

Comment: Can you provide the output of  `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk` ?

Comment: I added the output to the post.

Comment: Thanks. It is usually better to copy the Text output into a code-box instead of pasting an image.

Comment: Your mount options are not the problem right now, but your 2TB hard drive is not recognized by the system (should be in `lsblk` even if it not mounted). Can you see it in "Disks" tool ?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I will be adding the output from now on in a text. I thought it's better in screenshot. The hard disk was there in the "Disk" tool but it doesn't appear now. I think this happened after I changed the SATA port.

Comment: Edit the line starting with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` to be like the other lines, I mean that it should start with `UUID=ab37...`.  The items in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` are symlinks and I don't think `/etc/fstab` likes symlinks

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy .. How to do this? how to edit these lines?. I'm sorry it must be a basic question. I'm a new Linux user.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem with a simple solution.

I opened the "Disks" tool and turned on the automatic mount options.

Thanks for everyone tried to help.